# mock a multiple return value of function in a loop based on parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-mock

I'm trying to mock a function that based on a value that got returned before **that based on a parameter (collection_name)**.
this I succeed to do with side_effect, but the problem is that I'm trying to do it within a loop, and than it succeed only at the first iterate.

the function looks something like that:

```python
def collect_values(collection_names)
    res = list()
    for collection_name in collection_names:
        collection_obj = get_collection(collection_name)
        _values = collection_obj.find().distinct()
        res.append(_values)
    return res
```

this is what I tried so far:

```python
def test_collect_filters_values(self):
    def collections_side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
        collection_obj_mock = MagicMock()
        find_result_mock = MagicMock()
        if kwargs['collection'] == 'test_collection_1':
            find_result_mock.distinct.return_value = ['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3']
            collection_obj_mock.find.return_value = find_result_mock
            return collection_obj_mock
        elif kwargs['collection'] == 'test_collection_2':
            find_result_mock.distinct.return_value = ['val_4', 'val_5']
            collection_obj_mock.find.return_value = find_result_mock
            return collection_obj_mock

    collections = ['test_collection_1', 'test_collection_2']
    get_collection.side_effect = collections_side_effect
    result = _api.collect_values(collections)
    self.assertEqual(result, ['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3', 'val_4', 'val_5'])
```

Comment: I would get rid of the `if-else` and make it return a list that's dependent on some param, regardless of the collection you're passing.

Comment: how you'd do it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, but I guess your problem is that once you reach the first `return`, you won't make it to the second one. So you should think about a solution that dynamically creates the list, depending on `*args` or `**kwargs` (like appending a unique value for each collection based on its name).

Comment: Didn't see the loop

Comment: @slideshowp2 "for collection_name in collection_names:"